# How to programmatically remove default button style in android

Tags: android

I removed the background, but the shadow is still underneath the button.

I know the following property will remove the style of an XML button.

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

But, how can I accomplish this programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.selectableItemBackground, typedValue, true);
yourButton.setBackgroundResource(typedValue.resourceId);
```

Here you go!